# Mongo DB find() query for nested document

Tags: mongodb

I am new with MongoDB. I want to retrieve document based on condition on nested document.
Example :

```
db.user.insert([
{name:"abc",uid:"abc.b",pass:"abc3",follows:500,posts:78},
{name:"xyz",uid:"xyz.r",pass:"xyz4",follows:600,posts:78},
{name:"pqr",uid:"pqr.s",pass:"pqr5",follows:600,posts:78,
      comments:[{
                  uid:"abc.b",msg:"great"},{uid:"xyz.r",msg:"awesome"}
               ]}
])
```

Here, how to retrieve documents based upon condition equivalent to RDBMS as :

```
 select * where comments.user="abc";
```

By which I can get users commented by "abc".

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation)** to access the embedded array element in your query object. For example, the following will query for documents in the `user` collection on the `uid` field of the `comments` array with value `"abc.d"`:

```
db.user.find({"comments.uid": "abc.b"});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
db.user.find({"comments.user"="abc"})
```

Comment: This one is wrong though. '=' has nothing to do with conditional queries in MongoDB